# datetime.strptime() returns a formatting error with %f

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, strptime

I am currently trying to convert a number of seconds into minutes and seconds notation. I am using divmod and trying to turn the result into a datetime value. I have the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
processtime = 69.009
m, s = divmod(processtime, 60)
m= str(m)
m=m[:1]
s= str(s)
s=s[:5]
processstring= m+ ' ' + s
datetimeprocess = datetime.strptime(processstring, "%M %S.f")
```

However every time i do this I get this error:

```
ValueError: time data '1 9.009' does not match format '%M %S.f'
```

I'm fairly sure I have matched the format and I can't figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `%` before `f`:

```
datetimeprocess = datetime.strptime(processstring, "%M %S.%f")
```

Test results:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> processstring = '1 9.009'
>>> datetimeprocess = datetime.strptime(processstring, "%M %S.%f")
>>> print datetimeprocess
1900-01-01 00:01:09.009000
>>>
```

Comment: @Kprakash You're welcome. Sometimes we just need a second pair of eyes :)